# Trying to use LogMeIn API to access list of users in a node in PHP

Tags: php, curl, logmein

I am trying to use the API published by LogMeIn here.

https://www.logmeinrescue-enterprise.com/welcome/webhelp/EN/RescueAPI/API/API_Rescue_getGroup.html

At this point I'm just trying to see what it can/can't do, rather than having specific requirements.

Whatever method I try, I always seen to get a response back that indicates 'NOTLOGGEDIN', even after using the token method to first get the token from logging in and including that in my request or from using the login method where you supply the user name and password. (see also: https://www.logmeinrescue-enterprise.com/welcome/webhelp/EN/RescueAPI/API/API_Rescue_tutorial_authentication.html)

I've tried via CURL in PHP and via SOAP by copy pasting the example from the documentation.

Here is my most recent attempt in PHP, copying their docs SOAP method. (and yes, SOAP is enabled in my PHP installation.)

```
    $soapclient = new SoapClient("https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/api/api.asmx?wsdl");

    $loginparams = array (
        'sEmail' => $_POST['lmiuser'],
        'sPassword' => $_POST['lmipass']
    );

    $getgroupparams = array (
        'iNodeID' => 11956835
    );

    $loginResult = $soapclient->login($loginparams);

    print_r($loginResult);

    $getGroupResult = $soapclient->getGroup($getgroupparams);
    
    print_r($getGroupResult);
```

The 'nodeid' is just a number for a group the user account I'm using has access to and is taken by hovering over the node that contains the users I would like to view in the LMI admin console. When running the above code, it just prints out:

`stdClass Object ( [loginResult] => login_OK ) stdClass Object ( [getGroupResult] => getGroup_NotLoggedIn )`

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if the documentation is just poor or both.

The documentation I linked to above has an example that looks like this:

```
<?php
    $soapclient = new SoapClient("https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/api/api.asmx?wsdl");

    $loginparams = array (
        'sEmail' => 'some@email.com',
        'sPassword' => 'secretPassword'
    );

    $getgroupparams = array (
        'iNodeID' => 337364,
        'sAuthCode' => '4ahx...80u0'
    );

    $loginResult = $soapclient->login($loginparams);

    print_r($loginResult);

    $getGroupResult = $soapclient->getGroup($getgroupparams);
    
    print_r($getGroupResult);
?>
```

There is only 3 differences. I am using the user name and password I am feeding into it via POST, my request is missing the aAuthCode in the $getgroupparams array. (But why do I need that if I'm supplying the username and password, the auth code is something you supply if your using the token method as far as I can see, and if that is not the case, what would I even put in that spot? The above example is just a placeholder value) and the node id is different, but I've explained where I'm getting it from.

I did also trying using PHP curl, and the way I did it, I could see that the authentication method to supply the username then password and was working and returning an auth code, but when I used this in the subsequent CURL request, I was getting the same response back, that it's 'NOTLOGGEDIN' which implies to me that it has not accepted my authentication in some way. If I then changed the supplied username/password when trying either method to include a non-existent user/pass, then the response does change to 'INVALID_SECRETAUTHCODE' or similar to indicate that it was wrong, so I don't think that is the actual problem.

I've tried their own support, but they don't have a clue and just tell me it's 'not supported' probably because the people on their help desk have no idea about this sort of thing and spend most of their time with account/billing queries rather than deeper technical things.

Can anyone spot anything I'm doing wrong in this initial example attempt?